# Unresolved reference for applicationContext recycleview element (kotlin app for android)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm developing an android app in kotlin, and I want to have a button in every recyclerView element, which will launch an intent - the same in whole recycle view, but with different parameters(for now it's just position for testing, in final form that will be some value from database).

I write the following code for that(inside my adapter class):

```kotlin
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectViewHolder, position: Int) {        
        val Edit: Button = holder.view.EditButton
        Edit.setOnClickListener()
        {
            var projekt: Intent = Intent(applicationContext, Project::class.java)
            projekt.putExtra("id", position)
            startActivity(projekt)
        }
```

But I get "unresolved refference" error for *applicationContext*. I used buttons with intent like that before and that worked perfectly fine, though this is the first time I'm trying to do it inside recyclerView element.

How to make it work? Maybe I just take the wrong approach and it should be done in different way?

Edit: Complete adapter class file:

```kotlin
package com.example.legoapp127260

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.project_item_layout.view.*


class ProjectAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectViewHolder>()
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProjectViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        val projectRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.project_item_layout, viewGroup, false)
        return ProjectViewHolder(projectRow)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 2;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val projectName: TextView = holder.view.projectName
        val projectNames: Array<String> = arrayOf("Set 1", "Set 2")
        val Edit: Button = holder.view.EditButton

        projectName.setText(projectNames[position])


        Edit.setOnClickListener()
        {
            var projekt: Intent = Intent(Edit.context, Project::class.java)
            projekt.putExtra("id", position)
            Edit.context.startActivity(projekt)
        }

    }
}

class ProjectViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you put your complete Adapter class?

Comment: I can (and I just do that), though I didn't know how it will help, it's quite usual. And a lots of data are mocks for now, they will be readed from database in the final form, but i decided to firstly prepare basic structure of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get context from your button:

```kotlin
var projekt: Intent = Intent(Edit.context, Project::class.java)
projekt.putExtra("id", position)
Edit.context.startActivity(projekt)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I can do that.
Though now i get the mismatch typers error: "required context found intent", and "no value passed to parameters p1, p2". So I change the launching activityline to ```
startActivity(Edit.context, projekt)
```
Now it seems to work fine... expect that Android Studio still says "no value passed to parameter p2". What this p2 parameter could be? Androis studio didn't require such arguments before when i used StartActivity() function in other activities...

Comment: @Lyokoheros I've updated my answer. Now it should work fine I guess

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. 
Well, actually no my application still isn't working, but as I found out it's something within onResume function of Project activity.